# how do I add a date to the bottom of a list of dates in excel automatically on a daily basis

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a list of sequential dates (1/01/2012, 2/01/2012, 3/01/2012 etc) in a column in Excel. I want Excel to check the current date and add that date to the bottom of the range if it isn't there already. I only want this to happen once per day so that there are no redundant entries.

For example:

If the list ends at 2/06/2013 and I open the workbook on 2/06/2013, nothing would happen. However, if I opened the workbook again the next day, on 3/06/2013, then that date would be added to the bottom of the list automatically.

I also have two formulas I need copied into the next two cells of that row. If a date was generated for `A20`, the formulas would be on `B20` and `C20`. The cell references for year/month/date would need to increment by 1 (as in one row) for every new date entry.

For reference, the first formula is:

```
=SUMIF('Sheet1'!A:A,DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),'Sheet1'!C:C)`
```

And the other formula is similar enough to be redundant for the point of solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I worked out how to check the list and add a new date

```
Sub CheckDateAndEnter()
    If Sheet10.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value <> Date Then
        Sheet10.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1) = Date
        Sheet10.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(1, 2) = "=SUMIF('Sheet1'!A:A,DATE(YEAR(A304),MONTH(A304),DAY(A304)),'Sheet1'!C:C)"
    End If
End Sub
```

however, those cell references in the formula need to increment once for a new column each time this occurs and I'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: if you create an .xlsm file you can use VBA that runs when the workbook is opened.  then just add your checks to see if you have the most current date.

Comment: Since the "SUMIF..." is a string, you can insert the updated reference into it: "=SUMIF...YEAR("&<row_num>&"...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place this code into the "ThisWorkbook" Modules in the VBA Editor, and make sure you safe your file as a "macro-enabled workbook" it should work.

Hard-coding the formula here probably isn't the best method, and the way I've done it could be cleaner using the R1C1 notation.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Reference to your worksheet
Dim Entry As Range: Set Entry = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) ' The Last Populated Cell in Column A
If IsEmpty(Entry) = True Then ' Optional, Used to populate the first cell
    Entry.Value = Date
    Entry.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Formula = "=SUMIF('Sheet1'!A:A,DATE(YEAR(A" & Entry.Row & "),MONTH(A" & Entry.Row & "),DAY(A" & Entry.Row & ")),'Sheet1'!C:C)` "
    Exit Sub
End If
If Year(Entry) = Year(Date) Then
    If Month(Entry) = Month(Date) Then
        If Day(Entry) = Day(Date) Then
            Exit Sub ' Last Entry = Today, Do Nothing!
        End If
    End If
End If
Set Entry = Entry.Offset(RowOffset:=1) ' Last Entry != Today, Goto Next Row and create Entry.
Entry.Value = Date
Entry.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Formula = "=SUMIF('Sheet1'!A:A,DATE(YEAR(A" & Entry.Row & "),MONTH(A" & Entry.Row & "),DAY(A" & Entry.Row & ")),'Sheet1'!C:C)` "
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try this now and see how it works but I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Perfect, does everything I need. Thank you!